# Edited question returns to edit queue

Tags: support

I performed an edit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839048/how-to-save-data-temporarily-on-iphone), which was subsequently authorised.

However, when I clicked on "review" again, some time later, the same question was presented in the list for editing (First Questions) again.

In addition to this, I have seen some already-edited question presented in this list.

My question is, what are the criteria for presentation of questions to this list?  I checked the FAQ and couldn't find an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "first questions" tab in the review page is not an edit queue: It's a page that shows you the first questions asked from users. Editing them doesn't change the status of first questions asked from a user.

The purpose of the review pages is not just finding posts that needs to be edited, but also to find posts that are spam; answers that should be deleted because they are not answers but, e.g., a completely different question; answers that are merely a link (to an external site, or to a Stack Exchange question); questions that are off-topic, duplicates, not constrictive, not a real question, or too localized.
As it is common for new users to write as answer what should be a comment (or a different answer), or ask a question that has been already asked (or it is off-topic), the review page has two tabs dedicated to the first posts made from users: first answers, and first questions.

The only tab in the review page that has a different purpose is the "suggested edits" tab, which is shown to the users with the privilege of editing every post, and that reports a list of posts for which there is a pending suggested edit done from users without the privilege of editing every post. Users with the right privilege can approve, reject, or improve the suggested edits.

[image: screenshot]

If then you have enough reputation (actually it is 10,000), you can see the "close" tab in the review page, which shows the posts voted to be closed. (The screenshot has been taken from *Drupal Answers*, as I am not a 10k user on *Stack Overflow*; the same tab is visible in all the Stack Exchange sites, though.)

[image: screenshot]

If I look at the "first questions" page now, I see the following three questions shown on the top of the page.

[image: screenshot]

If then I look at the questions asked from those users, I get the following.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

The only way I have to not seeing a question again in the "first questions" tab is to click on the "review question" link that appears in that page. Once I do it, the question is not show for me anymore on that page.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Clearly, I disabled the random ordering, clicking on the link shown on the bottom of the page.

[image: screenshot]

As far as I can see, the questions shown in the "first questions" tab has been asked from users who asked not more than 5 questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer.  Accepted and upvoted.